# How add float x and float y values in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, scatter-plot, mpandroidchart

I am trying to use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) in my app but my dataset series contains float values (x and y data) and the library use `ArrayList<Entry>` that need float and int values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently that is not possible as you describe it, since the position on the x-axis can only be an integer (x-index).

However, you can of course scale that up and then represent float.